# How do I save the function result as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
# Import Module
import os
  
# Folder Path
path = "Enter Folder Path"
  
# Change the directory
os.chdir(path)
  
# Read text File
  
  
def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
  
  
# iterate through all file
for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is in text format or not
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
  
        # call read text file function
        read_text_file(file_path)
```

This code reads the text files and prints out everything from the text files, but I can't seem to change the printed output as a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Is the format of your text file compatible with the pandas `read_table` or `read_csv` functions?

Comment: compatible with read_csv

Comment: Then you should use `read_csv` to read the file and it will return a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: This code is used to read several files. I have about 20 files and each has over 4000 rows. So i wanted to use a function instead of having to manually sort through each file

Comment: `read_csv` is a function.

Comment: Can you give me a little hint on how I should start off the code... please.

Comment: You could, for example, read each file in with read_csv, then filter out the rows you want to keep, then combine the DataFrames with `append`. `read_csv` is almost certainly faster than iterating through the lines of the file processing each one separately.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. Thank you! You just helped me a lot!!